# Play 2.3: Passing model data via controllers

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a model class with a bunch of filters:

```
@Entity
public class MyModel extends Model
{
   String name;
   String filterA;
   String filterB;
   String filterC;
}
```

Basically I use this for a page with a search and search results.
It's quite simple when I submit a search because I simply post and use the `bindFromRequest()` to get all the filters.

But I found it a problematic when I wanted to paginate. I want to be able to remember these selected filters when the user is selecting a page. The pagination links are GET requests so I can't use `bindFromRequest()`. I looked around for `QueryStringBindable` but I couldn't understand how I could bind the model.

Ideally, I don't want to have to pass each filter to the pagination link because the number of filters could keep changing.

EDIT:

A better framed question would be that if I had a bunch of filters on a page, and I click another page number, how best can I send the filter information to the following page, so that all the controls can be populated? Passing each filter is not very clean as the number of filters can increase.

Comment: I think instead of creating entity for searchdata you can create a inner class in your main model like one described in [Play Sample](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/samples/java/computer-database-jpa/app/models/Computer.java).You can also handle those get request.

Comment: I had a look at that sample already. My problem is that the Page object only has a couple of filters, but I have many more and they can keep increasing. I was hoping there is a way to just persist all the filters into a user defined object. Just like how easy it is with submit.

Comment: Maybe serialising a JSON into a flash scope? or session?

Comment: Sorry but I dont think its a good thinking(what you described in question).As you know entity represent a table and you want to use it as it would allow you to save previous filter (not good approach accoding to me, creating new row everytime) and also you said `I want to be able to remember these selected filters when the user is selecting a page` what if before requesting for next page user changes search filter so why saving previous filter if it has the possiblity of changing for each request so it is good for passing filter for each request

Comment: I am not saving it as each row. I can remove the entity object. That doesn't matter. I just need to figure out how I can pass on the selected filters from page to page. When a user selects a new filter, it works fine because there is a submit button. But in the case of pagination, there is no submit button.

Comment: If you know a better way to do it, then I am open to new ideas. I would like to do it efficiently.

Comment: I would not suggest that but here it goes .Add id field in your above entity and in every paging request send send this id along with page number so that in controller you can do find by id to get model containing that filters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72129/discussion-between-nbz-and-singhakash).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to solve the pagination issue using QueryStringBindable. There is a great example on the docs - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/api/java/play/mvc/QueryStringBindable.html

Once I implemented this interface, I was able to pass MyModel as a parameter in the controller action for pagination and it would add the information to the url which works really well if you want to be able to copy paste links.